# RDP to Windows XP guest on kvm constantly reconnecting after logon

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding, kvm-virtualization

**ISSUE**

I have, after some days of "hard" work, managed to correctly configure kvm on a Centos 5.5 host.  I have 2 VM running successfully.  Since I only have one public IP address (for the kvm host) I am trying to setup port forwarding (using IP tables).  And everything seems to work fine.  When I rdp to 'hostname.com:3389' I successfully get the login screen for my Windows XP VM.

The problem starts after logging in...  As soon as I provided my credentials in the Windows XP VM the rdp session disconnect/reconnects...  It all happens so fast that I cannot really do anything (in a matter of seconds I am disconnected and reconnected again).

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

So what have I already tried/checked?
1. I tested the port forwarding the other VM (a Centos system) and I can successfully connect using ssh (and no disconnects).
2. I checked that after I created the iptables rules I could still access the host and the Internet from my Windows XP VM.

**LOGS/OUTPUT**

PREROUTING rule:

```
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            12.12.12.12       tcp dpt:21 to:192.168.122.1:3389
```

FORWARD rule:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24    state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

To me this all should work...  Unfortunately it does not!  Hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 0):

are you able to connect to the XP VM from behind the NAT? I mean another VM

Comment: Good point, I tried pinging the XP VM from my Centos VM and that did not work...  Then I remembered that XP has the firewall running by default.  After disabling this firewall I can connect (=ping) the XP VM without any issues from my other VM (which is behind the same NAT).  Unfortunately the same story when I try to RDP to the XP VM...  Keeps throwing me out as soon as my credentials are provided...  Anybody else any ideas?